# Running `mcelog` on an AMD processor

Tags: amd, mcelog

When I run `mcelog` (version 154), I get the following output.

```
mcelog: ERROR: AMD Processor family 23: mcelog does not support this processor.  Please use the edac_mce_amd module instead.
CPU is unsupported
```

This to me feels like a category error, because `mcelog` is an application and `edac_mce_amd` is a kernel module.

Moreover, I *do* have this module loaded. `lsmod` returns `edac_mce_amd 28672  0`.

So what is this error message *really* saying? Is there an alternative binary that I should be running to get MCEs from my AMD processor, or is there a way to make `mcelog` compatible?

The background for this is that I am getting sudden crashes about once a day with no incriminating messages in `journalctl`, so I am trying to see if there are MCEs that might be highlighting the problem.

Answer (score 6):

`mcelog` is [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig#n1121), you should use [`rasdaemon`](http://git.infradead.org/users/mchehab/rasdaemon.git) instead (also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/mchehab/rasdaemon), and probably in your distribution of choice).

If packaged versions of `rasdaemon` don’t appear to work with your CPU, try building a newer version; in particular, support for your CPU family requires at least version 0.6.3 of `rasdaemon`. (But even older CPU families might require recent versions of `rasdaemon`.)